# Integrating lists into Python/Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, python, selenium

What I am trying do is use a web page to create art template files so I don't have to do it manually.
The web page is hosted on our private domain so you can only access it through a computer on the domain. I have about 1000 of these to do currently and they are listed in a excel document(the excel/xlsx doc in the google drive link only has 24).

Preview of website - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ql14srIkjGvmCYU2bAP8ULRL6SMGeTQt/view?usp=sharing
Excel List - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ex05W-0P_OPo0uZaCzIMDLfPVRmh2ru8/view?usp=sharing

I have the "bot" working with making one template. The thing I need help with is being able to use a `ForEach` action on either a `.xlsx` or with a `.txt` if its easier. Then changing the `TemplateName` in the python script and repeating the part I annotated.

```
     from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
        import os
        import time

        TemplateName = ("test2") ## template to be made 
        
        PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)  ##chrome webdriver needs to installed for whatever version chrome you are using
    
        driver.get("http://UserName:Password@pulse1.pgd.com/Admin")  ## Allows for direct login to pulse rather then using login pop up window
    
       ## repeat from here down 
        driver.get ("http://pulse1.pgd.com/Admin/Templates/Create")  ## forwards you to the create template page
        time.sleep(1) ## gives time for page to respond
        
        ##repo
        TempName = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Name']")
        TempCode = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='Code']")
        FileName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Filename_chosen']")
        FileSearch = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='Filename_chosen']/div/div/input")
        OrderType = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('OrderType'))
        CreateBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/form/div[5]/div/input")
               
        ## create template
        OrderType.select_by_visible_text('print-template') ## selects Print-template from dropdown box
        TempName.clear()
        TempName.send_keys(TemplateName) ## Inputs template name
        TempCode.clear()
        TempCode.send_keys(TemplateName) ## Inputs same as template name
        time.sleep(1) ## waits 1 second for page to respond
        FileName.click()  ## clicks on search box
        FileSearch.send_keys(TemplateName + "\n") ## fills in search box and hits enter
        time.sleep(2) ## waits 2 seconds for art to load
        
        CreateBtn.click() ## Clicks to create template
```

I know not use `time.sleep` but i couldn't get the implicit wait to work.
I've only been learning this for 2 days so I'm kind of happy with what I got so far :)
Also didn't know what to name this question so feel free to change it or let me know what I should change it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read templates from a text file delimited by lf or cr\lf:

```
fp=open("mytext.txt","r")
lineread=fp.readline()
while(lineread):
    TemplateName=lineread.strip()
.
.  <do repeated section here>
.
    lineread=fp.readline()
fp.close()
```